# Trouble with ActiveX objects in HTA

Tags: activex, jscript, hta

I'm working on a chromeless HTA and found some code that allows you to minimize the window.  It works fine when I run the HTA from a local drive, but when I put it on my network drive (so I can access it from another computer), it suddenly says the object doesn't support the Click property.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function minWin(){
        MyObj.Click();
    }
</script>
<object Id="MyObj" CLASSID="clsid:adb880a6-d8ff-11cf-9377-00aa003b7a11">
    <param NAME="command" VALUE="minimize">
</object>
```

This works fine when run locally, but the Click() property throws an error when the HTA runs from a network drive.  Any idea why?

Comment: It is a security issue, that doesn't look like a full HTA definition can you provide the rest?

Comment: The full source includes some private data, so I only included the code specifc to the function I'm trying to perform.  Elsewhere in the file is a `<span>` element that has an onClick event that calls the `minWin()` function.

Comment: if you don't at least provide the HTA definition section, can't help you. The HTA definition defines what properties are set so `mshta.exe` can decide on the security context to use, without that we're just guessing. You don't need to include all the code, that isn't important just the HTA definition.

Comment: This is not unusual, a different security zone applies to network drives.  Probably takes Control Panel > Internet Options > Security tab > Local Intranet to allow ActiveX components to run.

Comment: @Ceetch also make sure you are not using any `<iframe>` inside your HTA without the [`APPLICATION` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536474(v=vs.85).aspx) set. See [Introducing HTML Applications: DHTML Goes out of the Browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250409(v=vs.85).aspx) *(especially the section **Frames and Security**)*.